# Getting react-native component props from event

Tags: javascript, react-native

In an event emitted from something like this:

```
function changed(ev) { /* ... */ }
<TextInput name='hello' onChange={changed} />
```

Is it possible to extract the `name` prop from the event inside of `changed()`?

```
function changed(ev) { console.log('name prop is', ev.???) }
```

and if so, is this stable across all events? The docs are not clear.

Comment: Why you're not using onChangeText property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can with refs, but I feel you are trying to work against the React Way(tm)...

```
inputChange(event) {
    console.log('name', this._input.props.name);
}

render() {
    return (
        <TextInput name="hello" onChange={this.inputChange} ref={(c) => this._input = c}/>
    );
}
```

You should have access to the 'name' prop from both inside the parent (after all its setting the value on the child) and from inside the child as part of its props values. So perhaps try to reevaluate on what you are trying to do :)

Comment: Thanks, any idea why the element isn't made available on the event itself? And I agree about there being a better pattern based on the example. I'm exploring different patterns for a more complicated usage.